# what does "but for that" mean here?

Tags: meaning

"But for that man she mightn't be going to Ireland; but for that, she might have been happy."

Comment: *But for the fire brigade, the house would have burned down.* It means: 'Had it not been for the efforts made by the fire brigade, the house would have been destroyed.' If you understand thus far, you should understand the sentence you quote. If you don't, let me know.

Comment: *But for (the actions/help etc. of) that man, she mightn't be going to Ireland*. Do you understand that much?

Comment: No disrespect, @svetlana, but I think what it means *here* is you're not a native speaker. ELU is more for *discussing* the use/history/etc. of English. If you're *learning* it, you might be more at home on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"But for that... [something happened]", in general, means "That is the only thing that ensured the something happened". Or in other words, "That [something] would not have happened if that were absent".

In this context, it means that the man was the cause of her going to Ireland. The second usage, because of the semi-colon usage, also is meant to refer to the man. However, because what we are told is the man is the only reason she goes to Ireland, the second usage of "but for that" expresses both going to Ireland as the direct cause of unhappiness and the man as the indirect but root cause (i.e. the direct cause of the direct cause) of her unhappiness.

Answer (score 0):

There is one sentence containing two propositions. The first proposition is that the man is the possible cause of her travel to Ireland (and she is in fact going there); the second is that her travel to Ireland is the possible cause of her unhappiness (and she is in fact unhappy).